# C# close console application when prompted?

Tags: c#, console

Is there a way in C# to close the Console Application when the user inputs a letter - without using the command 'Press any key to continue...' .

i.e. if I write the message 'Do you want to quit (y/n) ?' and the user inputs the letter y.

```
namespace Example
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("Do you really want to quit the Game? (y, n): ");
            char YN = Console.ReadLine()[0];


            if (YN == 'y' ||
                YN == 'Y')

            {

            }
            else if (YN == 'n' ||
                 YN == 'N')
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Continue Game...");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Input? You mean typing 'y/n' and pressing Enter? Or just pressing `y` or `n`?

Comment: ?? typing 'y/n' and pressing Enter?

Comment: Are you running your program using "Start Debugging" (F5) or "Start without Debugging" (Ctrl + F5)?  The "Press any key to continue" message is added by Visual Studio when not debugging so that you can see the console output before the application quits.

Answer (score 3):

Use Environment.Exit(0) inside Y condition

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("Do you really want to quit the Game? (y, n): ");
            char YN = Console.ReadLine()[0];


            if (YN == 'y' ||
                YN == 'Y')

            {
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }
            else if (YN == 'n' ||
                 YN == 'N')
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Continue Game...");
            }
        }
    }
}
```